# Which world view prevailed during other yugas

Tags: history, philosophy, yuga

Various philosophies or world views base on vedas are sankya, vaisheshika, purva mimansa, vedantha. What world views were in existence during other yugas? Say like during mahabharata and ramayana

Comment: I think Veda (including knowledge of Upanishad) may enough/efficient/effective in previous yugas. In other words, there may be not needed to provide any doctrine/philosophy to describe or explain Veda in previous yugas.